# Boto3 : Can we use actual data buffer as parameter instaed of file name to upload file in s3?

Tags: python-2.7, boto, boto3

I am using python with boto3 to upload file into s3 bucket. Boto3 support upload_file() to create s3 object. But this API takes file name as input parameter

Can we give actual data buffer as a parameter to upload file () function instanced of file name?

I knew that we can use put_object() function if we want to give data buffer as parameter to create s3 object. But I want to use upload_file with data buffer parameter. Is there any way to get out of this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: upload_file doesn't support fileobj at the moment.

Comment: What is the reason that not flushing the data buffer to physical file to fulfill upload_file() ?

Comment: I don't want to flush data to physical file due to security issue. It is third party data which is transferring through my machine.

At the same time I want to use server side encryption with customer key which is only supported in Boto3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to use a file-like object with `upload_file`. `put_object` and `upload_part` do support these, though you don't get the advantage of automatic multipart uploads.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I used set_contents_from_string
() from boto instead of upload_file() from boto3. set_contents_from_string() full fill my requirement for SSE with customer key